# Unable to add/remove tiles in clean Windows 8 installation

Tags: windows-8.1, live-tiles

I can't add/remove tiles to my start screen because right-clicking does NOT bring up a menu. I have a clean install of Windows 8.1. When I right-click a tile, it puts a check mark on it, but no menu pops up.

I did a clean install of Windows 8 and then updated to 8.1 (installed all current updates before 8.1).

Output of `sfc /scannow`:

[image: output of sfc /scannow]

Comment: The sole reason "problem" isn't allowed is because we want people to describe the problem in their title. Please [edit] and fix that – you could say something about the menu not popping up. Thanks.

Comment: You have corrupt files.  I would use the DISM tool to resolve the that problem.

Comment: slhck (what kind of username is that? Did you just hit random keys when creating you name?) I got my answer, so I don't think the title is a critical element. But thank you for your opinion.

Comment: slhck, yeah I could say "problem adding tiles to startscreen" since I have a problem, and I came here for help with my problem, you'd think I should say what I am having a problem with. If I was asking for an opinion, I'd say "what is your opinion about windows 8?" (windows 8 sucks).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because you are using a 3rd party theme which doesn't support the new right click menu of KB2919355. Update the theme to a compatible version or switch back to the inbox theme of Windows 8.1.